# Docker VSCode Extension - Unable to connect to Docker

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, windows-10

I've installed the [Docker extension for VS Code](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-docker) on Windows 10. I configured the following VSCode setting:  "docker.host": "tcp://0.0.0.0:2375"

Besides above VSCode settings I also created the following Environment variables:

```
DOCKER_CERT_PATH=C:\Users\\[user]\\.docker\machine\machines\default
DOCKER_HOST=tcp://0.0.0.0:2375
```

What else do I need to do to get this working?

Answer (score 0):

It depends if you are usig docker-machine (VirtualBox) or Hyper-V.

In both instance, if you see:

[image: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/986438/37055992-b3ccccfa-2148-11e8-9936-f6df601cdfd3.PNG], follow [Microsoft/vscode-docker issue 229](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-docker/issues/229) in order to debug the extension.
It could be an SSL certificate issue for instance.